# Unable to load text from textarea to docx

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, javascript-objects

Need to load outputTextElem text from textarea as a docx document on button click. But the existing method will not work:

```
const downloadBtn = document.querySelector("#download-btn");
downloadBtn.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
  const outputText = outputTextElem.value;
  const outputLanguage =
      outputLanguageDropdown.querySelector(".selected").dataset.value;

  if (outputText) {
    try {
      const result = await mammoth.convertText({ arrayBuffer: outputText }, {
        ignoreEmptyParagraphs: true
      });

      const blob = new Blob([result.value], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.download = `translated-to-${outputLanguage}.docx`;
      a.href = url;
      a.click();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error converting text to DOCX:", error);
    }
  }
});
```

......

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mammoth/1.4.2/mammoth.browser.min.js"></script>
```

An error occurs that the type cannot find mammoth.convertText, although everything is connected in index.html as indicated above:

```
script.js:216 Error converting text to DOCX: TypeError: mammoth.convertText is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:205:36)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The [docs for Mammoth](https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js) state that the library is a _"docx to HTML converter"_ (not "text to docx"). And there is no mention of a "convertText" method anywhere.  Are you sure you are using the correct lib? Where did you find the `convertText` method?

Comment: I don't remember where.  How to implement it then?